# Property sets alternatives?

Tags: google-search-console

I work with a website that has localised versions on different domains. Every domain is added to Google Search Console as a separate domain property. But under the hood it's just the same website in different languages.

Sometimes we need to treat it all as just one website. For example, when connecting to Google Looker Studio. It would help to have a grouped/combined/merged property, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

The closest I found is the Property sets feature, but it was [deprecated](https://www.seroundtable.com/property-sets-no-longer-supported-in-google-search-consol-27169.html) in 2019.

Can this be accomplished?

I was hoping I could create a generic property and add all other domains to it as aliases, but it doesn't seem possible.